# Проблема с хуком

Tags: wordpress

Текст выводится, но его не видно. Почему так?
Хук пишу в файле function.php

```html
add_action('wp_footer', 'method');

function method()
{
    echo "this is being called";
}
```

Comment: откуда же вы знаете, что он выводится?

Comment: ctrl+f и текст )

Comment: смотрите в инспекторе браузера, какие у него стили. а вообще, без картинки и разметки в инспекторе браузера - это не вопрос, а загадка

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: echo заменить на return

Comment: `method` - никогда не рискуй, используя общепринятые термины для названия функций. Приучить делать уникальные префиксы/суффиксы

Comment: Не видя пациента только гадалки могут ответить на вопрос.